# How to build shared libraries of qwt - how to prevent qmake from linking to QtCore and QtGui

Tags: qt, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have the source code of **qwt** and while making shared libraries of **qwt** , I want to prevent **qmake** from linking to QtCore and QtGui

Looking forward to guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. qwt uses Qt, so there's no way to build it as a shared library without linking it to QtCore/QtGui. To import Qt's symbols, it has to be linked to QtCore/QtGui **import** libraries - that's how qmake sets it up. Otherwise, the linker would have to emit a qwt library with a whole bunch of unresolved symbols, and it simply wouldn't work - it'd crash on the first reference to a Qt symbol, given that said symbol would have an address of zero.

To build it without linking it to Qt it has to be built as a static library. It will be then linked to Qt when the executable is linked.